# Editing files within a project outside the GUI

Tags: qgis, editing

I'm using QGIS 2.12 Lyon on Windows 10.
Is there a way to edit the files/layers contained within a project other than the Layers Panel? My project takes a very long time to load and the status bar shows one particular file/layer 'loading...'. I can't track the file down in the GUI.

Comment: What type of GIS data you are reading ?

Comment: Creating spatial indices and primary keys speeds up most data types (except slowly responding online services).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The saved project file (on windows .qgs) is just a text file. You can read/edit this in a text editor. Many other QGIS related files are also text files.

This means that it is entirely possible to change details of your saved project outside of QGIS. The downside is that you need to understand the file structure.

If you are making simple changes the job is an easy one. If you make a mistake you may break the saved project entirely (keep a copy of the original!).

The project file does not contain the displayed data - just instructions about where to find the data (including basemaps) that is displayed. The project file does contain information about how the data is displayed (symbology, details about what's displayed at what scale, and so on).

Comment: Make a copy of the project file and modify that. You can always return to the original if something gets broken.

Comment: Good point @AndreJ - have added a couple of words to my answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

The project is just reference to location of shape files or any other formats.
Either you hide all layers except the layer you want to edit or open new instance for QGIS with the layer you want to edit. Also make sure you are display layers by scale, so layers with lots of details (large scale) will not appear unless you zoom in and vice versa.